# Overriding CSS given a name, ID and class

Tags: css

I'm trying to override the background colour in form-control, but it doesn't seem to change. Here's what I'm doing:

```
#guide .form-control
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

The HTML:

`input type="text" id="guide" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only the class selector is enough.

You wrote `#guide .form-control`, it means an element whose a class of `.form-control` **and also** descendant of an element whose id of `#guide`. It's different than `#guide.form-control` (without the space).

```css
.form-control
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="guide" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is id #guide and `class` `.form-control` is at the same level. Hence, no space is required between them.

```
#guide.form-control{ ... }
```

Though, if not necessary you can just have only class or id.

```
#guide{ ... }

.form-control{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override it remove space between two selectors

```
#guide.form-control
{
     background-color: #000000;
}
```